# Adding property to Symfony BaseModel

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have the below symfony model and I need to add a `name` property (see below) to the existing model and then update the database accordingly. What is the proper way to accomplish this? I appreciate any suggestions.

I tried running php bin/console doctrine:database:drop and then php bin/console doctrine:database:create, hoping it'll make the necessary mappings, without any success, I am getting the following error: `You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine".`

This seems to be overly complicated and I am sure theres a simpler way to accomplish this. I appreciate any suggestions.

composer.json snippet

```
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
```

NoticeSettings.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

class NoticeSettings extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table      = "notice_settings";

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     */
    protected $notice;

   /**
    * @Assert\Type(type="string")
    */
   protected $name;
}
```

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
parameters:
    locale: en
    uploads_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads'

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets:
        version: 15

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:      ["form/fields.html.twig"]
    globals:
        user: "@app.user"
        badges: '@app.sidebar_badges'
    paths:
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/views': ~
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/TwigBundle/views': 'Twig'
```

Comment: Your model does not seem to contain any Doctrine mapping information, only validation used by forms. Could it be that you are using Propel rather than Doctrine for mapping to the database? The concept of extending a base model and referring to the table (via the property) inside the model seems to fit this ORM better than Doctrine.

Comment: Please show your *config.yml* file

Comment: Please see edited for my config.yml file.

Comment: @dbrumann, no, we're not using propel, we're using doctrine, as you can see in the composer.json file. Also, when output the list of commands, all the doctrine commands I need are listed, but I am getting a 'ServiceNotFoundException' when trying to call any of them.

Comment: In that case it would be helpful to see where the Doctrine mapping is configured. I assume either in the base model or in a separate configuration in the bundle under `Resources/config/`. The ServiceNotFoundException seems odd as well. Can you post the command you are executing + full exception output? Seeing the stack trace might help understanding what's wrong

Comment: Your config.yml does not contain any configuration for Doctrine. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Doctrine is not fully configured in your application. This is likely also why the service can not be found.

Please make sure that inside your AppKernel.php the DoctrineBundle is registered (search for `new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle()`).

Next you will need the doctrine configuration. [You can check the repository if you need a reference configuration](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.0/app/config/config.yml#L40-L60):

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

Also make sure, that your parameters.yml and parameters.yml.dist contain the values needed by the configuration. Again you can take [the file from the official repository as a reference](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.0/app/config/parameters.yml.dist#L5-L11).